# How to enable multi touch gesture in phonegap android?

Tags: android, cordova, gesture, multi-touch

I have come across a strange problem. I am showing an image within my android application. 
And I want to enable multi-touch gesture but it is not working. I have found that in 
samsung galaxy it works but not on other devices. Do you have any ideas guys how can I 
make the thing work for all devices.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Multitouch inside the android browser is only working for version from android 3.x

But you need to cancel a touch move to get another one. Take a look here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html

Answer (score 1):

For Android devices with 2.x there is a solution about upgrading your phonegap project for multitouch using. Try this library: https://github.com/Philzen/webview-multitouch-polyfill

I use it on Android 2.3.3 with cordova-2.2.0 in Eclipse and i get a second touchevent:

```
    document.getElementById("yourDOMelement").addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            if(event.touches.length >1){
                // more than one touch event
            }               
    },false);
```